# Can't understand the second benefit of "Single Responsibility Principle"

Tags: oop, single-responsibility-principle

In the book "Agile Software Development: Principles, Patterns, and Practices", the "Single Responsibility Principle" section has an example about a class `Rectangle` which has more than one responsibility:

```
class Rectangle {
    public void draw() { ... }
    public double area() { ... }
}
```

And different classes may use only one of its methods:

```
class ComputationalGeometryApplication {
    Rectangle rectangle;
    public void someMethod() {
       double area = rectangle.area();
    }
}

class GraphicalApplication {
    Rectangle rectangle;
    public void someMethod() {
       rectangle.draw();
    }    
}
```

(Note: The book takes `c++` for example, and I use Java code here since I'm not familiar with `c++`)

I'm not clear about this sentence:

> Second, if a change to the GraphicalApplication causes the Rectangle to change for some reason, that change may force us to rebuild, retest, and redeploy the ComputationalGeometryApplication.

Say if `GraphicalApplication` causes the `draw()` method to become `draw(boolean)`, why will it force us to rebuild, retest, and redeploy the `ComputationalGeometryApplication`?

I mean,

1. `ComputationalGeometryApplication` can choose to use the old version of compiled file of `Rectangle` if we know the changes causes by `GraphicalApplication` is not related with itself
2. If `ComputationalGeometryApplication` wants to use the new version of `Rectangle`, yes, we should rebuild/retest/redeploy. But even if the `draw()` method is not in `Rectangle`, but in another class of same codebase, we still need to rebuild/retest/redeploy the `ComputationalGeometryApplication` if we want to use the new version of the library which contains `Rectangle`

I can't really understand the benefit, what am I missing?

---

Update: The referenced question did help me a lot, since there is a slight difference with the two questions, I want to add my understanding here.

The key is this sentence in the accepted answer of that question:

> "If the GraphicalApplication requires a new method or change in semantics in the Rectangle class, then that affects the ComputationalGeometryApplication since they both "link" to the Rectangle library"

The keyword `link` reminds me the `Rectangle` is in a shared library. When it's changed by `GraphicalApplication`, the `ComputationalGeometryApplication` will automatically uses the new version of the `Rectangle` class. If the change to the `Rectangle` is not compatible with previous one, say, it adds some references of extra class in the constructor of `Rectangle`:

```
class Rectangle {
    Rectangle() {
       SomeExtraClass cls = new SomeExtraClass()
    }
}
```

For `ComputationalGeometryApplication`, it will fail if we didn't rebuild it since it may not find the class `SomeExtraClass` when initialise the `Rectangle` class